# jQuery Dropdown behavior when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having some difficulty getting this drop down to behave correctly. When you hover-over the element that gets dropped down, it should stay open. I made a function that every half-second checks if your mouse is hovered over that element, and if it is, it does nothing, and if it isn't, it closes the dropped down menu. Here is my Fiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/KyCyB/

here is my JS:

```
$('.navBarClickOrHover').mouseover(function () {
    var targetDrop = $(this).attr('targetDropDown');
    if ($('.dropdownCont[isOpen="true"]').length != 0) {
        $('.dropdownCont[isOpen="true"]').attr('isOpen', 'false');
        $('.dropdownCont[isOpen="true"]').animate({
            "height": "0px"
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#' + targetDrop).attr('isOpen', 'false');
            $('#' + targetDrop).animate({
                "height": "200px"
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('#' + targetDrop).animate({
            "height": "200px"
        });
    }
}).mouseout(function () {
    var targetDrop = $(this).attr('targetDropDown');
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('#' + targetDrop).attr('isHoveredOver') == 'true') {
            //DONOTHING
        } else {
            $('#' + targetDrop).animate({
                "height": "0px"
            });
        }
    }, 500);
});

$('.dropdownCont[isOpen="true"]').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).attr('isHoveredOver', 'true');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).attr('isHoveredOver', 'false');
});
```

I'm sorry for the long and repetitive code, I was going to make it a bit more Object Oriented once I got it to work right, I just kept messing with it to try and get it to work the way I want it to. Definitely stuck. if you've missed the link before, here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/KyCyB/
Any help or a different approach to this would be awesome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with css

Here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/IsOFaJE/1/edit

I also made a version that uses javascript to slidedown/up: http://jsbin.com/IsOFaJE/2/edit

Here is the html:

```
<div>
    title
    <ul>
        <li>menuitem</li>
        <li>menuitem</li>
        <li>menuitem</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
ul {display: none; }
div:hover ul,
ul:hover { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Can it animate in CSS? That'd be sweet, much easier.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, in the OP's code there's also a delay that handles the mouseleave time.

Comment: Trying to utilize this now

Answer (score 0):

After about another 30 minutes or so, I erased all of the code and started a new strategy, this is what I came up with and it works splendidly:

```
$('.navBarClickOrHover').mouseenter(function(){
            var targetDropDown = $(this).attr('targetDropDown');
            $('.dropdownCont').each(function(){
                $(this).css({
                    "height":"0px"
                });
            }); 
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#'+targetDropDown).animate({
                    "height":"200px"
                });
            },500)

        }).mouseleave(function(){
            var targetDropDown = $(this).attr('targetDropDown');
            if($("#wrapper").find("#"+targetDropDown+":hover").length == 0){
                $('.dropdownCont').each(function(){
                    $(this).animate({
                        "height":"0px"
                    });
                });
            }
            else{
                $('#'+targetDropDown).bind('mouseleave', checkIfHoveredFunc);
            }
        });

        var checkIfHoveredFunc = function(){

            $('.dropdownCont').each(function(){
                $(this).animate({
                    "height":"0px"
                });
            });

        }
```